# Apply 1D function on one axis of nd-array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython

## What I want:

I want to apply a 1D function to an arbitrarily shaped ndarray, such that it modifies a certain axis. Similar to the `axis` argument in `numpy.fft.fft`.

Take the following example:

```
import numpy as np


def transf1d(f, x, y, out):
    """Transform `f(x)` to `g(y)`.

    This function is actually a C-function that is far more complicated
    and should not be modified. It only takes 1D arrays as parameters.    

    """
    out[...] = (f[None,:]*np.exp(-1j*x[None,:]*y[:,None])).sum(-1)


def transf_all(F, x, y, axis=-1, out=None):
    """General N-D transform.

    Perform `transf1d` along the given `axis`.

    Given the following:
      F.shape == (2, 3, 100, 4, 5)
      x.shape == (100,)
      y.shape == (50,)
      axis == 2

    Then the output shape would be:
      out.shape == (2, 3, 50, 4, 5)

    This function should wrap `transf1d` such that it works on arbitrarily
    shaped (compatible) arrays `F`, and `out`.

    """
    if out is None:
        shape = list(np.shape(F))
        shape[axis] = np.size(y)

    for f, o in magic_iterator(F, out):
        # Given above shapes:
        #   f.shape == (100,)
        #   o.shape == (50,)
        transf1d(f, x, y, o)

    return out
```

The function `transf1d` takes a 1D ndarray `f`, and two more 1D arrays `x`, and `y`. It performs a fourier transform of `f(x)` from the `x`-axis to the `y`-axis. The result is stored in the `out` argument.

Now I want to wrap this in a more general function `transf_all`, that can take ndarrays of arbitrary shape along with an `axis` argument, that specifies along which axis to transform.

### Notes:

- My code is actually written in Cython. Ideally, the `magic_iterator` would be fast in Cython.
- The function `transf1d` actually is a C-function that returns its output in the `out` argument. Hence, I couldn't get it to work with `numpy.apply_along_axis`.
- Because `transf1d` is actually a pretty complicated **C-function** I cannot rewrite it to work on arbitrary arrays. I need to wrap it in a Cython function that deals with the additional dimensions.
- Note, that the arrays `x`, and `y` can differ in their lengths.

## My question:

How can I do this? How can I iterate over arbitrary dimensions of an ndarray such that at each iteration I will get a 1D array containing the specified `axis`?

I had a look at `nditer`, but I'm not sure if that is actually the right tool for this job.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np


def transf1d(f, x, y, out):
    """Transform `f(x)` to `g(y)`.

    This function is actually a C-function that is far more complicated
    and should not be modified. It only takes 1D arrays as parameters.

    """
    out[...] = (f[None,:]*np.exp(-1j*x[None,:]*y[:,None])).sum(-1)


def transf_all(F, x, y, axis=-1, out=None):
    """General N-D transform.

    Perform `transf1d` along the given `axis`.

    Given the following:
      F.shape == (2, 3, 100, 4, 5)
      x.shape == (100,)
      y.shape == (50,)
      axis == 2

    Then the output shape would be:
      out.shape == (2, 3, 50, 4, 5)

    This function should wrap `transf1d` such that it works on arbitrarily
    shaped (compatible) arrays `F`, and `out`.

    """

    def wrapper(f):
        """
        wrap transf1d for apply_along_axis compatibility
        that is, having a signature of F.shape[axis] -> out.shape[axis]
        """
        out = np.empty_like(y)
        transf1d(f, x, y, out)
        return out
    return np.apply_along_axis(wrapper, axis, F)
```

I believe this should do what you want, although I havnt tested it. Note that the looping happening inside apply_along_axis has python-level performance though, so this only vectorizes the operation in terms of style, not in terms of performance. However, that is quite probably of no concern, assuming the decision to resort to external C code for the inner loop is justified by it being a nontrivial operation in the first place.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I was busy. Your solution does work. I've posted a Cython/C-API solution down below that I found meanwhile. However, I'm not sure if it's really worth the effort. Btw, if you know a better way to do this in Cython, please let me know. For now I'm going to use your solution, and only resort to the  C-API approach when I really have to.

Answer (score 0):

#### To answer your question:

If you really just want to iterate over *all but* a given axis, you can use:

```
for s in itertools.product(map(range, arr.shape[:axis]+arr.shape[axis+1:]):
    arr[s[:axis] + (slice(None),) + s[axis:]]
```

Maybe there's a more elegant way to do it, but this should work.

#### But, don't iterate:

For your problem, I would just rewrite your function to work on a given axis of an `ndarray`.  I think this should work:

```
def transfnd(f, x, y, axis, out):
    s = list(f.shape)
    s.insert(axis, 1)
    yx = [y.size, x.size] + [1]*(f.ndim - axis - 1)
    out[...] = np.sum(f.reshape(*s)*np.exp(-1j*x[None,:]*y[:,None]).reshape(*yx), axis+1)
```

It's really just the generalization of your current implementation, but instead of inserting a new axis in `F` at the beginning, it inserts it at `axis` (there might be a better way to do this than with the `list(shape)` method, but that was all I could do.  Finally, you have to add trailing new axes to your `yx` outer product, to match as many trailing indices you have in `F`.

I didn't really know how to test this, but the shapes all work out, so please test it and let me know whether it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The first part seems like a good quick-fix. However, I doubt that this would benefit much from Cython in terms of speed. About your second part. I might not have been clear on that, but `transf1d` is actually far more complicated and in C. Hence, rewriting it to arbitrary shape is not going to work.

Comment: Sorry, just realized that your first answer is somewhat the opposite of what I want to do. If `a` had shape `(10, 2, 3)`, then iterating over it would yield parts of shape `(2, 3)`. My C-function cannot deal with this. I want the opposite: I want to iterate such that each part is of shape `(10,)`.

Comment: Bummer, double miss. Sorry about that! See my edit for a better iteration.  Nothing I can do about the `transfnd` without more information about what the actual function does.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of iterating over all but one axis in Cython using the Numpy C-API (Code down below). However, it's not pretty. Whether it's worth the effort depends on the inner function and the size of data.

If any one knows a more elegant way to do this in Cython, please let me know.

I compared to Eelco's solution and they run at a comparable speed for large arguments. For smaller arguments the C-API solution is faster:

```
In [5]: y=linspace(-1,1,100);

In [6]: %timeit transf.apply_along(f, x, y, axis=1)
1 loops, best of 3: 5.28 s per loop

In [7]: %timeit transf.transfnd(f, x, y, axis=1)
1 loops, best of 3: 5.16 s per loop
```

As you can see, for this input both functions are roughly at the same speed.

```
In [8]: f=np.random.rand(10,20,50);x=linspace(0,1,20);y=linspace(-1,1,10);

In [9]: %timeit transf.apply_along(f, x, y, axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 15.1 ms per loop

In [10]: %timeit transf.transfnd(f, x, y, axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.55 ms per loop
```

However, for less large input arrays the C-API approach is faster.

### The code

```
#cython: boundscheck=False
#cython: wraparound=False
#cython: cdivision=True

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
np.import_array()

cdef extern from "complex.h":
    double complex cexp(double complex z) nogil

cdef void transf1d(double complex[:] f,
                   double[:] x,
                   double[:] y,
                   double complex[:] out,
                   int Nx,
                   int Ny) nogil:
    cdef int i, j

    for i in xrange(Ny):
        out[i] = 0
        for j in xrange(Nx):
            out[i] = out[i] + f[j]*cexp(-1j*x[j]*y[i])


def transfnd(F, x, y, axis=-1, out=None):
    # Make sure everything is a numpy array.
    F = np.asanyarray(F, dtype=complex)
    x = np.asanyarray(x, dtype=float)
    y = np.asanyarray(y, dtype=float)

    # Calculate absolute axis.
    cdef int ax = axis
    if ax < 0:
        ax = np.ndim(F) + ax

    # Calculate lengths of the axes `x`, and `y`.
    cdef int Nx = np.size(x), Ny = np.size(y)

    # Output array.
    if out is None:
        shape = list(np.shape(F))
        shape[axis] = Ny
        out = np.empty(shape, dtype=complex)
    else:
        out = np.asanyarray(out, dtype=complex)

    # Error check.
    assert np.shape(F)[axis] == Nx, \
            'Array length mismatch between `F`, and `x`!'
    assert np.shape(out)[axis] == Ny, \
            'Array length mismatch between `out`, and `y`!'
    f_shape = list(np.shape(F))
    o_shape = list(np.shape(out))
    f_shape[axis] = 0
    o_shape[axis] = 0
    assert f_shape == o_shape, 'Array shape mismatch between `F`, and `out`!'

    # Construct iterator over all but one axis.
    cdef np.flatiter itf = np.PyArray_IterAllButAxis(F, &ax)
    cdef np.flatiter ito = np.PyArray_IterAllButAxis(out, &ax)
    cdef int f_stride = F.strides[axis]
    cdef int o_stride = out.strides[axis]

    # Memoryview to access one slice per iteration.
    cdef double complex[:] fdat
    cdef double complex[:] odat
    cdef double[:] xdat = x
    cdef double[:] ydat = y

    while np.PyArray_ITER_NOTDONE(itf):
        # View the current `x`, and `y` axes.
        fdat = <double complex[:Nx]> np.PyArray_ITER_DATA(itf)
        fdat.strides[0] = f_stride
        odat = <double complex[:Ny]> np.PyArray_ITER_DATA(ito)
        odat.strides[0] = o_stride

        # Perform the 1D-transformation on one slice.
        transf1d(fdat, xdat, ydat, odat, Nx, Ny)

        # Go to next step.
        np.PyArray_ITER_NEXT(itf)
        np.PyArray_ITER_NEXT(ito)

    return out


# For comparison
def apply_along(F, x, y, axis=-1):
    # Make sure everything is a numpy array.
    F = np.asanyarray(F, dtype=complex)
    x = np.asanyarray(x, dtype=float)
    y = np.asanyarray(y, dtype=float)

    # Calculate absolute axis.
    cdef int ax = axis
    if ax < 0:
        ax = np.ndim(F) + ax

    # Calculate lengths of the axes `x`, and `y`.
    cdef int Nx = np.size(x), Ny = np.size(y)

    # Error check.
    assert np.shape(F)[axis] == Nx, \
            'Array length mismatch between `F`, and `x`!'

    def wrapper(f):
        out = np.empty(Ny, complex)
        transf1d(f, x, y, out, Nx, Ny)
        return out

    return np.apply_along_axis(wrapper, axis, F)
```

Build with the following `setup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

setup(
    name = 'transf',
    ext_modules = cythonize('transf.pyx'),
    include_dirs = [np.get_include()],
)
```